# Difference between calling a variable and creating a new value of the variable

Tags: scala

I am pretty sure this is something very simple that is going over my head, but if you can give me some clarity as to why in the following code snippet the third println(p()) returns 10 instead of 11. The final output is 5 8 10 7, I understand all of them except the moment it returns 10.

```scala
class A(var x : Int) {
  def f() : () => Int = {
    var y : Int = 1
    () => {y = y + 2; y + x}
  }
}

object ClosureM2 {
  def main(args : Array[String]) : Unit = {
    var a = new A(2)
    var p = a.f()
    println(p())
    a.x = 3
    println(p())
    a = new A(4)
    println(p())
    p = a.f()
    println(p())
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want clarity, don't write code like this.

Comment: Perhaps you could explain why you think it should print `11` rather than `10`?

Comment: It's an exam question, for me it would print 11 since after redefining a with the x value of 4, in f() y is 7 so 7+4=11

Comment: We're calling `f()` on `p` though, and `p` is still pointing to the old instance of `A(3)` not to `A(4)` which is assigned to the variable `a`. So it returns `7 + 3 = 10` instead of `7 + 4 = 11`.

Comment: Why is it still pointing to the old one though?

Comment: Because that's what we tell it to point to. We don't tell it to point to `a`, where we call `f()`. We point directly to the function `f()` inside of the instance of the class `A`.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you drop whatever course you are on that is setting questions like that and find a proper functional Scala course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're getting caught out where `a` is reassigned to `A(4)`.

When we assign `f()` to the variable `p`, `p` is set to the function `f()` inside of the class `A`, not to the variable `a`:

```scala
var a = new A(2)
var p = a.f()
```

This means that when `a` is reassigned with `a = new A(4)`, `p` doesn't point to the new `A` we have assigned to `a`. It is still pointing to the previous instance `A`.

Because of that, when `p()` is called again it calculates to `7 + A(x = 3)` which evaluates to `10`.